# $n \times n$ matrix whose entries $\in \{1,2\}$, such that $7$ divides the sum of every column and $5$ divides the sum of every row

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The question is if such a matrix can exist. The problem specifies $n=9$.

My attempt was to do a summation of the sums of the columns over the entire matrix, which is equal to the sum of all entries. $7$ clearly divides this sum, as it divides each of the summands. Analogously for the rows. We can then deduce that the sum of all entries of the matrix is divisible by $7$ and $5$ and thus is divisible by $35$. Moreover, we know that this sum has a lower bound of $81$ (if it were filled with $1$'s only) and an upper bound of $162$ (if it were filled with $2$'s only). Then the total sum is either $105$ or $140$. For $105$ we can reason as follows: suppose the matrix is filled with $1$'s only and you can increase the entries to equal $2$. At the beginning all of the columns sums are equal to $9 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$, therefore in each column addition to the entry has to be performed at least $5$ times. In total at least $45$ changes to the matrix have to be made, but our total sum of $105$ only allows $105-81=24$ changes to the matrix. Thus, the total sum cannot be $105$.

I haven't been successful with the case where the total sum equals $140$. I am not sure whether this is due to an unhelpful proof technique or because the claim is true and requires construction.
It would also be interesting to see how this generalises to arbitrary $n$. My approach outlines above would seem to be pretty friendly towards generalisation, but again, I am not certain if it will be able to arrive at a result.

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose such a $9 \times 9$ matrix exists. We consider every column of the matrix. The sum of every column is at least $9$ and at most $18$. Since the sum is divisible by $7$, then the sum must be $14$.

As a result, the sum of the numbers in the entire matrix is $9 \times 14 = 126$. But, as you have mentioned, the sum should have been divisible by $5$ too. So, no such matrix exists.